# how to reset checkboxes in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I have a check box binded to an array--the array is type Interface which is the following:

```
        export interface IdataTypes {
          Categories: string,
          isSelected: boolean,
        }
```

here is how bounded it:

```
      <div *ngFor="let DT of DTofSectores">
        <input type="checkbox"
               name="DTofSectors"
               formControlName="DTofSectors"
               value="{{DT.Categories}}"
               (change)="onDataTypeClick($event,DT,'DTofSectors')"
                           >
        {{DT.Categories}}
      </div>
```

the check box is filled according to what is selected from a dropdown list. My question is: how can I clear all checked check box when I change the dropdown.

EDIT: I have tried to set the binded array to null whenver the dropdown changes as following

```
        this.DSofSectores.push({
          category :"",
          isSelected : false
        })
```

but what happen is that, the array remain empty do i have no checkbox then!

Comment: Set every `DT.Categories` to `false` ?

Comment: so what I tried was to set the array to [], whenever the dropdown changes. But what happen is when i change the dropdown all the boxes will be chacked! I cannot put the DT.Categories  to "false" since it is type string[].

Comment: your use of form controls and checkboxes is a bit off.  Each checkbox is an independent control requiring it's own form control.  Otherwise every checkbox will just be the same control and you will have no way of independently setting them.  If you want only one item to be selectable at a time and use the same form control, you should use a radio form.

Comment: no multi selection is possible. the number of check boxes varies depending on what is selected from dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Simply trigger a function when the value in drop-down changes (with ng-change) and make ng-checked = "false" for all the checkboxes. For simplicity, bind the checkboxes with a value that changes to false whenever dropdown value changes

Comment: strangely, I do not have ng-change, i am using" ngModelChange"!! I am newbie not sure if that is an issue, but it works well. then if I put "ng-chacked=false ", again all the boxes will be checked in case of changes